# Differences between various Object value gathering Methods in JS

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a simple example where I can gather the value of an Object property in the following two ways:

***Object***

var obj = {name:"Peter", age: "23"};

***Method 1***

obj.name

**Method 2**

obj['name']

I think in both the methods we using the key of an object to access its value. So what is the difference?

**OR**

Why do we need 2 methods if we can do the same thing with both?

Answer (score 1):

This one `obj.name` is called dot notation and this one `obj['name']` is called as bracket notation.

> *Why do we need 2 methods if we can do the same thing with both?*

`Bracket notation` will help you to access a property which is having a `key` that doesn't qualify a `valid variable name`.

Ex:

```
var x = {"#12":"Hello"};
console.log(x["#12"]); //Hello
```

Where you can't use dot notation, like `x.#12`. Since that would be an invalid syntax.

Comment: Any other differences than the name ? means functional differences?

Comment: Really? You think that a downvote on [an answer like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35891674/1) needs a comment?

Comment: @Juhana Yeah I accept it. But how can I type everything in a minute. I was editing it.

Comment: Nobody says that you have to answer within a minute. Post the answer only after you've finished writing it, or accept that you can get downvotes when you post garbage just to get the first answer in.

Comment: @Juhana Is SO have any constraint that I have to wait for certain time to post an answer? Whether it is going to be a first answer or last answer, at the end which one is gonna have a good content. That is the point. A person who used to write garbage can see garbage in everything. Let the answerers to make edits. Otherwise do whatever you want. No one is gonna care.

Comment: You posted a bad answer and got a downvote. Then you edited the answer and the downvote was removed. What's the problem? Just don't post "@downvoter care to comment" when you *know* why you got the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Square bracket notation allows use of characters that can't be used with dot notation:

```
var foo = myForm.foo[]; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myForm["foo[]"]; // correct syntax
```

The second advantage of square bracket notation is when dealing with variable property names.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  someFunction(myForm["myControlNumber" + i]);
}
```

**Roundup**:

Dot notation is faster to write and clearer to read.
Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables
Another example of characters that can't be used with dot notation is property names that themselves contain a dot.

For example a json response could contain a property called bar.Baz.

```
var foo = myResponse.bar.Baz; // incorrect syntax
var foo = myResponse["bar.Baz"]; // correct syntax
```

Reference : [From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)